# Specific ID attribution pattern past 100 entities

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgsexpression

I have an ID attribute which looks like this on the attribute table of a given layer:

```
A00
A00
A00
A01
A02
A03
...
A98
A99
```

A00 is specifically given based on a certain attribute manually given (for this example I made it MARKING_ATTRIBUTE). So far I only had projects that never go beyond 100 attributes and so I used some basic expression that worked fine for anything less than 100 entities on my layer:

```
CASE 
    WHEN MARKING_ATTRIBUTE = '0' THEN concat('A00') 
    WHEN $id = 0 THEN concat('A01') 
    WHEN $id = 9 THEN concat('A10') 
    WHEN $id < 9 THEN concat('A0',$id+1)  
    WHEN $id > 9 THEN concat('A',$id+1) 
END
```

I'm not entirely sure how to make it work since A63 for example could have $id = 111 and thus messes up the id attribution, it's probablematic we reach A100+

Comment: So, if `$id` were `63`, you want to write `A64`. What should happen if `$id` were e.g `123`? Would the output be `A124`? or is the logic more complex?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially it.  The added complexity is probably the fact that there are multiple A00 entities as they so A01 could have an $id of 27 for instance. Off the couple projects  I have tried this expression on, it becomes probablematic past the 100th entity

Comment: So, you're okay with e.g. no entry like `A28` if the manual override for `$id=27` were `0`?

Comment: Also, your solution is a bit complicated, but viable for IDs beyond 100.

Comment: Here's a sreenshot from an example: https://imgur.com/a/gPchdza
As you can see it skips from A86 to A113 which in my case isn't suitable

Comment: So you want a continuous ID for all features who don't meet the restriction?

Comment: I didn't understand, but try this: `'A' || lpad ($id, 3, '0')`

Comment: That's not the solution OP wants @pigreco . They need a continuous ID only for rows which aren't restricted by an entry in another field.

Comment: Yes @Erik that's exactly it.